# Differences between Code OSS and Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

As developers stated [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60#issuecomment-161792005),

> The cool thing about all of this is that you have the choice to use the Visual Studio Code branded product under our license or you can build a version of the tool straight from the vscode repository, under the MIT license.
>
> Here's how it works. When you build from the vscode repository, you can configure the resulting tool by customizing the product.json file. This file controls things like the Gallery endpoints, “Send-a-Smile” endpoints, telemetry endpoints, logos, names, and more.
>
> When we build Visual Studio Code, we do exactly this. We clone the vscode repository, we lay down a customized product.json that has Microsoft specific functionality (telemetry, gallery, logo, etc.), and then produce a build that we release under our license.

Given that I'm not able to build from source by myself, if I install VSC and replace product.json with the clean version, will I have the same effect?

Comment: Interestingly yes. I just tried it myself and replaced the `licenseUrl` entry and upon restart it indeed opened the new URL when using Help=>License. However there are a several entries (like `dataFolderName` or `applicationName`) which I suspect won't respond as nicely as the license url to on-the-fly changes.

Comment: Those unwilling or unable to build VSC from source might find the VSCodium project useful: https://vscodium.com/

Answer (score 54):

Shortly:

- **Code - OSS** is an open source project without any proprietary code.
- **Visual Studio Code** is a distribution of the Code - OSS repository with Microsoft specific customizations released under a traditional Microsoft product license.

Also you can find [more information here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Differences-between-the-repository-and-Visual-Studio-Code)

Comment: Ok, so who build/made **Code - OSS**, is that also by Microsoft, but with the MIT license and no telemetry

Comment: If you are afraid of telemetry you can run *Code - OSS* in podman container without access to host network, I tend to use this approach in more and more apps I run on my desktop. Have a look how this can be done: github.com/grzegorzk/osscode_in_podman