# Why can't i search for vs code extensions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So i have fresh Manjaro installation and only software i have is ws code and some bloatware.

But when i want to search for extesions like C/C++ it find somethink but not what i need.

This is what i get

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAv8a.png)

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcn1P.png)

I find something like product.json but i cannot find its location or anything.
I tried reinstalling... nothing.

Also I can't find it as .vsix file so i don't know what to do.

Search for solution on internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're using is Code - OSS and not VSCode; they're built from *almost* the same source except for the telemetry and the part that handles the marketplace (the latter being a proprietary component by Microsoft). As far as I know it's not possible to have VSCode's Marketplace working for another editor. Code - OSS relies on [Open VSX Registry](https://open-vsx.org).

References:

[Differences between Code OSS and Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867739/differences-between-code-oss-and-visual-studio-code)
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Differences-between-the-repository-and-Visual-Studio-Code

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know the difference and vscode works just fine, I don't mind some proprietary code.

Answer (score 1):

Kamen's answer explains it pretty well. However, there is a workaround. You can go to the browser marketplace and search for the [C/C++ Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack). On the right, under "Resources", there is a "Download Extension" link. It will download a vsix file which you can install in Code by searching for `Extensions: Install from VSIX...` in the command palette (`ctrl + shift + p`).

Comment: that command is also in the Extension bar top menu (`...`)